# Bug in new navigation custom tabs tags

Tags: bug, new-nav

I noticed that when I have two (I haven't tested with more) tags in a single tab, and then go back to a tab with a single tag, it shows the single tag questions, but the second tag still remains visible, i.e. it's a visual bug.

It only happens when:

1st and single tag in the tab are equal:

See the following images as an example:

This is the single tag tab: (`Java` for example):

[image]

Later we change to another tab I have saved as "Custom Painting" with `Java` + `custom-painting` tags:

[image]

Then we go back to the "Java" tab:

[image]

It correctly shows the same questions as the first one, but the tag `custom-painting` remains visible.

It doesn't occurs when switching to, let's say "Spring", because it "refreshes" all the tags...