# Switching from "Unanswered" to "All Questions" leaves incorrect tag filter in search box

Tags: bug, search, filtering, tag-watching

I recently noticed a weird behavior if I follow the steps on the Stack Overflow home page -

1. Click "Questions"
2. Click "Unanswered button"
3. Make sure "My tags" is selected
4. Click on "All Questions" again.

This takes me to a page where the search input is filled with all my favorite tags. Since that takes an intersection of all the tags, I don't see a single question. Shouldn't it just revert to whatever the questions that were shown before Step 2?

Can the search string be changed to take a union of the tags instead of intersection. Because I think intersection of favorite tags will hardly be of any use.

[image: Screenshot of Bug]

It can be noted that the RSS link below says "C or C++...". So the intended behavior was Union, but the search string is still `[c] [c++]` instead of `[c] or [c++]`.

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome / WIn 10

Comment: I only have two tags, `python` and `pandas` as my faovrite tags. Worked as expected. Chrome/Win 10

Comment: @MattR as expected as in you were shown questions with both the tags or either of the tags? I guess pandas would always have python with it, but were you shown questions with only python?

Comment: Repro'd on Windows 10 Firefox 56.0. Three of my favorite tags are python, fortran, and idl-programming-language, which are mutually exclusive and I get no results. I get lots if I manually edit in the "or"

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, Was only shown questions with both `python` and `pandas`

Comment: @MattR Exacltly, but I believe it should show questions with any of the favorite tags. For some one who visits `javascript`, `c` and `linux-kernel`, it shows empty results.

Comment: Nice find. I don't think it should be changed to anything, if I'm on the `my tags` tab it doesn't mean that I want my search to be populated with all my tags when I click on `all questions`. It should just be fixed and don't do anything. From playing with it for a couple of minutes there are also some other bugs related  to search and `unanswered`.

Comment: Reproduced on chrome/android.

Comment: I've had the new tabs for so long I had forgotten this was even an option

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349939/bug-in-new-navigation-custom-tabs-tags

Comment: I am surprised on the VtC, these are entirely different questions. Both are asking for a feature of the tag-based search, but that is it.

Comment: I just stumbled across this bug myself, and thought I'd leave a note that it still exists after the responsive design and tag watching changes.